# JSON get key/value: if non-existing, JS just stop. How to workaround to set the array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Given a large JSON table in localStorage and a given key provided by the user, I access an associated value. But if the value and/or the key doesn't exist, then I want to create them. However...

**Given the following JSON:**

```
var data = [ 
{ 'myKey': 'A', 'status': 0 },
{ 'myKey': 'B', 'status': 1 },
{ 'myKey': 'C' },
{ 'myKey': 'D', 'status': 1 }
];
```

And **the following JS:**

```
function getJsonVal(json, itemId) {
    for (var i in json) {
        if (json[i].myKey == itemId) {
            return json[i]; 
        }
    }
}
```

If I...

```
// request non-existing-in-JSON value:
valC = getJsonVal(data, 'C');
alert("this is C's value: "+ valC)
```

or

```
// request non-existing-in-JSON key:
keyE = getJsonVal(data, 'E');
alert("this is E: "+ keyE);
```

the script just stop midway.

**I wished to have some error value allowing me to made something like `If ( null|| undefined ) Then create new key/value`, but my script just stop because there these items are not existing. Any work around ?** Jsfiddle appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the typeof operator you can safely check, whether a property is set

```
function getJsonVal(json, itemId) {
    for (var i in json) {
        if (typeof json[i].myKey != 'undefined' && json[i].myKey == itemId) {
            return json[i]; 
        }
    }
    return 'someDefault';
}
```

Comment: If i understand well, this is only to check the property is set. Right ?

Answer (score 1):

My revisions to your sample code:

http://jsfiddle.net/dqLWP/

```
var data = [ 
{ 'myKey': 'A', 'status': 0 },
{ 'myKey': 'B', 'status': 1 },
{ 'myKey': 'C' },
{ 'myKey': 'D', 'status': 1 }
];

function getJsonVal(json, itemId) {
    for (var i in json) {
        if (json[i].myKey == itemId) {
            return json[i]; 
        }
    }
}

var output = getJsonVal(data, 'E');
alert("this is the outputted value: "+ output);

if ( ! output) {
    alert('time to create that new key/value you wanted');
}
```

Comment: what does means the ( ! output) in simple English ?

Comment: [Solution here](http://jsfiddle.net/dqLWP/3/) @Lyndon: I wisht to accept your answer, please clarify "(! output)" in plain english and append your answer's IF with: data.push({'myKey': 'E', 'status': 1});

Comment: "!" negates an expression. "if ( ! true)" basically means "if (false)" More: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators

Comment: So !output means "if output doesn't exist"or "indefined", I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are setting values for variables `C` and `E` somewhere, you need to put them in quotes:

```
// request non-existing-in-JSON value:
valC = getJsonVal(data, 'C');
alert("this is C's value: "+ valC)

// request non-existing-in-JSON key:
keyE = getJsonVal(data, 'E');
alert("this is E: "+ keyE);
```

Also, you should alert the variables you set (`valC` or `keyE`).

Comment: Good shot! Done. Thanks Jeff.

Answer (score 0):

To improve Lyndon's answer:

```
function getJsonVal(json, itemId) {
    for (var i in json) {
        if (json[i].myKey == itemId) {
            return json[i].status; // add .status here so you can see the value of keys that exist and have one.
        }
    }
}
```